# Calculating Phi(M) and D for RSA decryption given p,q,e

Tags: encryption, rsa, cryptanalysis

I've been given a message in 4 digit numbers but it doesn't seem to work when I use my calculated values for phi(m) and d. If I'm correct phi(m) = (p-1)(q-1) correct? And d is given by ed = 1mod(phi(m))? And from this, it can be calculated by the smallest number in which ed-1 can be divided by phi(m)?

Comment: Indeed, if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, and $m=p\cdot q$, then $\varphi(m)=(p-1)(q-1)$. And any integer $d$ such that $\varphi(m)$ divides $e\cdot d-1$ is a private exponent making RSA _work_, in the sense that $0\le x<n\implies{(x^e\bmod n)}^d\bmod n=x$. More precisely, RSA _works_ if and only if $\lambda(m)=\operatorname{lcm}(p-1,q-1)$ divides $e\cdot d-1$. Perhaps your difficulty is with how you define _seem to work_, or make the calculations.